# Trusting Cognito accessToken in lambda (authorizer in use) - Authorization

Tags: authentication, jwt, authorization, amazon-cognito, lambda-authorizer

Is it safe for my lambda function to trust the accessToken passed by the user and checked by the lambda authorizer to perform CRUD db operations?

For example:

```
const authToken = event.headers['Authorization'];
if (!authToken) throw new Error('No auth token found so no username');
var decodedToken = jwt_decode(authToken);
const userName = decodedToken.username;    //---- BUT CAN WE TRUST THIS? ----
let params = {
  TableName: "myTable",
  IndexName: 'userName-gsi',
  KeyConditionExpression: 'userName = :userName',
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':userName': userName,
  },
  Limit: 1,
};
let data = await dynamodb.query(params).promise();
return {
  statusCode: 200,
  headers: utils.getResponseHeaderApplicantifyCors(),
  body: JSON.stringify(data.Items[0]),
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example you're only decoding the JWT, so the only verification made is that the token is in JWT form. That is not enough to guarantee, that the JWT is originating from trusted party.

The minimum you should do, is to also verify the contents of the JWT token. Steps for that are listed here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-verifying-a-jwt.html

Comment: Thanks L3p1 that's a super useful link. I guess I will have to figure out if the lambda authorizer used with cognito does all 3 steps already or if I have to do some manually.